# tie breaker listing items from highest to lowest score

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I read through some of the other tie breaker-related threads but didn't seem to find this exact solution...

The old tie-breaker question again.

In column A are the point values from a psychology test, with the related need listed in column B.

I found a formula to list the values in order from highest to lowest in column C.

I am looking for way to then list the needs according to the score from highest to lowest (Column D), because then I have a formula that I am running based on the top 2 results. There is a tie between 2 of them but I need to list the results for each out separately.

I have tried a few different formulas but none have quite worked.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NvYR.png)

Comment: Why not just sort them using built-in functionality?

Comment: cuz its part of a semi automated quiz, the answers will be different every time and I want it to be automated for the user..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first:

```
=INDEX($B:$B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$2:$A$7)/($A$2:$A$7 = LARGE($A:$A,1)),1))
```

For the second:

```
=INDEX($B:$B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$2:$A$7)/($A$2:$A$7 = LARGE($A:$A,2)),COUNTIF($C$2:$C3,LARGE($A:$A,2))))
```

[image]

To get the list in Column D:

```
=INDEX($B:$B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($B$2:$B$7)/($A$2:$A$7=C2),COUNTIF($C$2:C2,C2)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Scott! That seemed to do waht I was looking for... awesome :)